# DALI Command's reply to the meaning of representatives

Tags: dali

I have some control gears which already have short addresses, are connected on DALI lines.
I tried to send Query Short Address (command 269)& verification Short Address (command 268), but I didn't get any response.Is this right?

If above is right, I tried to send command 153, I got response 06 and when I tried to send command 144 I got response 04.

What is the meaning of these responses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command 269 Query Short Address and Command 268 Verify Short Address are in the range covered by the Initialise command. Command 258 Initialise starts or retriggers a 15 minute timer, the commands 259 to 270 are only processed within this period.

In addition, Command 269 Query Short Address won't give any response if the random address doesn't equal the search address.

Command 268 Verify Short Address will only respond with Yes if the data in the command matches the short address of the gear, in the special format of shifted left one place, with LSB set to 1.

Command 153 Query Device Type with response 06 means LED device type.

Command 144 Query Status has a bitwise interpretation, you need to read the standard IEC62386-102 for the definition.

Answer (score 0):

The command 144 returns the status information of the gear. You are getting the response 04, assuming it to be hex value i.e 0x04, it means bit2 = 1 which implies Lamp arc power-on status is 'ON'

Similarly, command 153 returns the Device type but I am not quite sure but I guess it should mean LED as the DT6(Device Type 6) designates LED.

and I am also not quite sure why you are not getting any response to the commands 268, 269. More information is required from your side as it entirely depends on the system you are using to assign short addresses in the first place!

EDIT: Source: [DALI Standard Preview](https://webstore.iec.ch/preview/info_iec62386-102%7Bed2.0%7Db.pdf)

Comment: assuming it to be hex value i.e 0x04, it means bit2 = 1 which implies Lamp arc power-on status is 'ON'
Why do you know that?Where can I get the information?

Comment: The gears already have short address on the dali bus .

Comment: Check section 9.16 of the link provided for further details